update partition id after doing disk swap
I am trying to create RHEL 9 image on AWS. I am using Packer and Ansible to create that image. We are swapping the root volume at one point in time. It works till that point. After the root volume is swapped, old EBS volume is detached and new EBS volume where we swapped the old EBS volume becomes root volume. When the VM restarts, it gets stuck and below error message is showing up on EC2 Serial Console (Screenshot):

As you can see in the screenshot, it is referring to the old volume partition which does not exist. I have no idea where/how to update what to make it realize that the partition id it is referring to is not there anymore and it should use the new partition.
